# jhipster angular 5 redirect after close modal

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am currently working on a JHipster 4.14.1 / Angular 5 project.

I have a modal with two buttons (print and cancel) When the user clicks the 'print' button, an HTTP request is sent to the server and the user is supposed to be redirected to this URL http://localhost:8080/#/ticket-seat-pdf-viewer. In the other case, when the user click the 'cancel' button, the modal is simply closed.

When click 'print' button modal closed and app redirect to the entity list, not redirect to http://localhost:8080/#/ticket-seat-pdf-viewer.

Here is my code :

```
private onSellSuccess(result: TicketSeat[]) {
        this.eventManager.broadcast({ name: 'ticketSeatListModification', content: 'OK'});
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.activeModal.dismiss(result);
        this.router.navigate(['/ticket-seat-pdf-viewer']);
    }
```

Comment: remove '/' in the `command` array

Comment: Thanks Chol for your time. I remove '/' in the router line, but appear this error in the console NavigationCancel(id: 10, url: '/ticket-seat-viewer(popup:ticket-seat-sell)')                                                       Object { id: 10, url: "/ticket-seat-viewer(popup:ticket-seat-sell)", reason: "Navigation ID 10 is not equal to the current navigation id 11"